# rails equivalent print_r

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging

I am looking for a method in rails that will print out the object and its associations.

I can use the following:

```
<%= debug @post %>
```

But the problem with this is if they post has comments the comments are not printed out, so I would have to do the following:

```
<%= debug @post.comments %>
```

Does a method exist which will print out the whole object and associations to the view.

I have seen a few posts on here but they all only talk about `debug` method

Cheers

Eef

Comment: Any method that does recursion would have to be written so that it doesn't end up in an endless loop because of self-referential structures. I think this is why only the top-level object is described.

Comment: Why not use the ruby-debug gem and manipulate the object as necessary in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the console you can do

```
y @post
```

In the controller you can do

```
logger.info {@post.to_yaml}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
<%= @post.inspect %>
<%= debug @post %>
```